# condition on radio button onclick, if false don't check

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

onclick of one radio button i have to check one condition if true i have to check it or restore to same old status,

**html**

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio0" onclick="myFunction()" checked /> 
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio1" onclick="myFunction()" /> 
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio2" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

**JS**

```
globalCondition = false;
function myFunction()
{
   if(globalCondition)
   {
      //some codes and it will check clicked radio button anyway 
   }
   else
   {
       return false; // i tried this but its not working
      /*here i don't want to check clicked radio button, and previously
       checked button should be checked*/ 
   }
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vL4FF/ Just use `onclick="return myFunction()"` or http://jsfiddle.net/2LAaD/ pass event object to your function then use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Return will not do anything as your onclick attribute does not "return" the function's value. Use preventDefault() instead (or actually return the value)!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Totally agreed that's why I used _or_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment `return` in the function will not do anything as you're not returning the function value in the in-line code.

Although the other solutions offered are correct, to keep your code *unobtrusive*, you should not have inline JS at all (remove the `onclick=`'s).

I realize the question was not tagged `jQuery`, but maybe it should have been: Instead on `onclick` you should use a jQuery event handler, selecting only the set of radio buttons.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/KVwL3/1/

```
globalCondition = false;

$(function(){
    $("[name=test]").click(function(e){
       if(globalCondition)
       {
          //some codes and it will check clicked radio button anyway 
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
            // or
            e.preventDefault();
           /*here i don't want to check clicked radio button, and previously
           checked button should be checked*/ 
       }
    });
});
```

### Notes:

**DOM ready event:**

`$(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE});`

**Selectors**

If an attribute `[]` selector `=` value contains special characters it needs to be quoted:

### e.g.

```
$('[name="IstDynamicModel[SD_WO_CREATE]"]')
```

There are any number of selectors that will choose just the three radio buttons. As this is a simple one-off connection, at startup, there is no real speed difference between any options, but you would normally try and make the selector specific in ways that might make use of various lookup tables available to the browser:

### e.g.

```
$('input[type=radio][name="IstDynamicModel[SD_WO_CREATE]"]')
```

This will be slightly faster as it will reduce the slowest check (the `name=`) to only `radio` `input`s.

Comment: my radio button list name is `IstDynamicModel[SD_WO_CREATE]` it showing `unrecogonized expression` error when i am giving like ` $("[name=IstDynamicModel[SD_WO_CREATE]]").change(function(e){` can i use ID instead of name???

Comment: JQuery tries to interpret the [] brackets, so just put quotes around ='isDynamicModel[SD_WO_CREATE]' or use ID "starts with" matching. E.g $("[id^=radio]"). There are many ways to match those 3 radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
globalCondition = false;
function myFunction(e)
{
   if(globalCondition)
   {
      //some codes and it will check clicked radio button anyway 
   }
   else
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false; // i tried this but its not working
      /*here i don't want to check clicked radio button, and previously
       checked button should be checked*/ 
   }
}
```

Comment: what is `e` here is it `this` of that element ??

Comment: if you assign myFunction to the radio's click event, 'e' is gonna be the event that triggers the code or in simple words, the mouse position and the things that the mouse does(in your case clicking and setting the radio to be checked).

Comment: @Satpal thatnks for providing the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

USe like this

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio1" onclick="return myFunction()" />
```

javascript

```
globalCondition = false;
function myFunction(e)
{
   if(globalCondition)
   {
      //some codes and it will check clicked radio button anyway 
     return true;
   }
   else
   {

       return false; // i tried this but its not working
      /*here i don't want to check clicked radio button, and previously
       checked button should be checked*/ 
   }
}
```